# Bitmask and selecting even bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm reading a book that states:

> To select all the even bits in a 32 bit unsigned int, we can AND the
>   number with the bitmask 0xAAAAAAAAAA, which is a 32 bit number with
>   even bits set (0xA is a decimal 10, 1010 binary). For selecting odd
>   bits we can AND with bitmask 0x5555555555, which is a number with all
>   even bits set (0x5 is decimal 5, 0101 in binary)

What I don't get is how 0x or 1010 sets all even bits to 1. If you go from right to left starting from zero clearly it is the odd bits that are set. What am I missing?

Comment: "_If you go from left to right_" There's your problem. Digits start from the right and increase in value to the left. I could append a zero to the left and it could be the exact same number.

Comment: oops it was a typo. i meant right to left. for example the right most bit (index-0) in 1010 is 0 (even), index-1 bit  (odd) is 1, index-2 bit (even) is 0. For example index-2 bit is even, it should be set to 1, but it's zero. that's what i meant.

Comment: It depends on your point of view, is the first bit (the LSB) number 0 or number 1? Traditionally it's 0, and it fits well with everything else in C being zero-based, however it goes against all traditional numbering.

Comment: bit 0 is the most right-hand-side bit, or LSb(note: small "b").

Comment: Bits are enumerated from bit 0 and upwards. They are not enumerated from 1 and upwards. So your book is incorrect, for odd numbers you need a 0xA mask and for even numbers you need a 0x5 mask.

Comment: @Lundin thank you!! that's what i needed to hear. i realised a few hours ago that my mistake was starting from zero (as always) instead of 1. but glad to hear that the index should indeed be starting from zero. but the thing is, do a quick google search and you will see many articles also following the authors method for using bit mask 0xA for even numbers and 0x5 for odd. you should make an answer explaining this so i can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left to right thing is where you make a mistake.

See what happens when you actually do it:

In binary 32-bits:

```
your number: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

Mask:        1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010

result:      1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010
```

The first bit (from the right!!!) is odd, and will be not get set when using `0xAAAAAAAAAA` as bitmask using the `AND` operator. Only the even bits will get set. Always start at the least significant bit.

Comment: yes i was starting at LSB, just a typo in my OP (fixed). I'm not sure what you mean by "uneven" and "filtered". Index 2 from right is set to 0, when it should be 1.

Comment: Fixed therms, not sure what you mean by saying the index is wrong, its fine how it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the position of the bits from right (LSB) as first bit (Odd) and second bit (Even).